# Does the implicit function theorem say something about this?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a smooth $F:\Bbb{R}^4\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for any open $U\in\Bbb{R}^3$ there is no smooth $g:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ with $F(x,g(x))=0$ (provided $F$ takes the value $0$)?

Comment: Please share you thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, consider the case that $F$ does not depend on the last coordinate (into which $g$ is inserted), but does depend on the first three in a non-trivial way, so $F(x,y) = \tilde{F}(x)$. Then
$$
F(x,g(x)) = \tilde{F}(x),
$$
and this need not be zero on any open neighborhood $U$, only at the original point where $F$ took the value zero.